# How to truncate trailing space in xargs

Tags: bash, unix, xargs

I would like to use xargs to list the contents of some files based on the output of command `A`. Xargs replace-str seem to be adding a space to the end and causing the command to fail. Any suggestions? I know this can be worked around using for loop. But curious to know how to do this using xargs.

```
lsscsi |awk -F\/ '/ATA/ {print $NF}' | xargs -L 1 -I % cat /sys/block/%/queue/scheduler
cat: /sys/block/sda /queue/scheduler: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is output of `lsscsi` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is *not* with `xargs -I`, which does *not* append a space to each argument, which can be verified as follows:

```
$ echo 'sda' | xargs -I % echo '[%]'
[sda]
```

Incidentally, specifying `-L 1` in *addition* to `-I` is pointless: `-I` *implies* line-by-line processing.

Therefore, it must be the output from the command that provides input to `xargs` that contains the trailing space.
You can adapt your `awk` command to fix that:

```
lsscsi | 
  awk -F/ '/ATA/ {sub(/ $/,"", $NF); print $NF}' | 
    xargs -I % cat '/sys/block/%/queue/scheduler'
```

- `sub(/ $/,"", $NF)` replaces a trailing space in field `$NF` with the empty string, thereby effectively removing it.
- Note how I've (single-)quoted `cat`'s argument so as to make it work even with filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
lsscsi |awk -F\/ '/ATA/ {print $NF}'| awk '{print $NF}' | xargs -L 1 -I % cat /sys/block/%/queue/scheduler
```

The first awk stmt splits by "/" so anything else is considered as field. In this is case `"sda "` becomes whole field including a space at the end. But by default, awk removes space . So after the pipe, the second awk prints $NF (which is last word of the line) and leaves out " " space as delimiter. awk { print $1 } will do the same because we have only one word, "sda" which is both first and last.

Comment: Please do not simply dump code, provide an explanation too

Comment: @arco444, Please do not simply dump  an explanation unless the questioner needs. Allow OP to think and understand that unless changed by -F option, awk treats "  " space as filed delimiter and does not include it, so the last valid word becomes $NF.

Comment: @JayKumarR, answers aren't just for the OP, but for everyone -- and per discussion/consensus reached on meta, code-only answers are only good form when "self-documenting, concise, and complete". This may be concise, but I wouldn't call it self-documenting.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques for an even more conservative view as to when code-only answers are appropriate, and links to further discussions on the topic.